# Rails 4: Render today's events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am not sure how to do this. I am currently using:

```
    <% @events.each do |event| %>
        <li><%= link_to event.group.name, event %>
        <%= event.start_time %>
    <% end %>
```

Obviously, this is rendering EVERY event. Can I make some kind of  statement to render the events for JUST today?

The above code is in the view. Is it a better idea to render the events from the controller? Or is it fine in the view?

EDIT: 
Wow, thanks for all the help guys! But, bear with me as I am a rails rookie. So I have changed my controller to this (based off of @Triveni Badgujar's answer:

```
  def home
    @resources = Resource.all
    @events = Event.where('DATE(created_at)= ?', Date.today)
    @homeworks = Homework.all
  end
```

This code however, has not had an affect on my home.html.erb view page. It is still showing ALL events instead of today's. 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the events with `start_time` as today, you can use:

```
@events = Event.where('start_time >= ?', Time.now.beginning_of_day)
```

Or if you want all the events that are created today, you can use:

```
@events = Event.where(:created_at => Date.today)
```

Comment: Thanks this is close to what I want in code that is easy enough for me to understand and manipulate.

Answer (score 2):

```
@events = Event.where('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d")= ?', Date.today)
```

Comment: I got a syntax error when I tried this: SQLite3::SQLException: near ")": syntax error: SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d"))= '2015-05-28')

Comment: Still have a syntax error: 
SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: DATE_FORMAT: SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d")= '2015-05-28')

Answer (score 1):

You should render your events in view, but you should filter them in controller. So your question is really a question about controller code. What you should do is call a scope on events. Like this:

```
@events = Event.where('start_time > ?', Time.now.beginning_of_day)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the controller you can write

```
@events = Event.where('DATE(created_at)= ?', Date.today)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a scope inside your event model to get all the events for today:

```
scope :todays_event, where('start_time=?', Time.now.beginning_of_day)


<% @events.todays_event.each do |event| %>
   <li><%= link_to event.group.name, event %>
   <%= event.start_time %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You really want a combination of the above answers:

Create a scope in the events model. Your scope may want to check that it is not before the end of the day as well

```
scope :todays_events, where('start_time >=? AND start_time <= ?', Time.now.beginning_of_day, Time.now.end_of_day)
```

Use that scope in the controller

```
@events = Event.todays_events
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
current_time = Time.now
@events = Event.where(start_time: current_time.beginning_of_day..current_time.end_of_day)
```

It will fetch all events between today's begging and end time.

Probably create a scope in `Event` model class like so to make it DRY:

```
scope :happening_on, ->(date_time) { where(start_time: date_time.beginning_of_day..date_time.end_of_day) }
```

This enables you to check events happening on ANY given day:

```
@events = Event.happening_on(Time.now) # todays events
@events = Event.happening_on(1.day.ago) # yesterdays events
@events = Event.happening_on(1.day.from_now) # tomorrows events
```